# Vuelidate - How to disable buttons if input field validation have no errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate to validate some fields of a user form that is divided into four steps. The validations seems ok, I just need to understand how to correctly translate the error messages, anyway I need to disable the buttons to go to next step if there are errors with validations.

I've tried in this way

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="v$.$invalid">Next</button>
```

But the buttons will stay always disabled also if there aren't errors into the form fields compilation from the user.

How I can achive this correctly? I have a lot of properties so I'm looking for a quick way to achive this.

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve]? Use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-local-projects-via-cli) or similar. Have you tried logging `v$.$invalid`? Use `<pre v-text="JSON.stringify(v$.$invalid, null, 2)" />` to see its contents in real time, in the `<template>`.

Comment: I've tried to log the`v$.$invalid` in watch method of vue, but nothing logged. I need to test your suggestion

Comment: Are you using Vue 3? `v$` is not defined globally in Vue 3. You need to return it specifically from `setup()` function. See [example](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#alternative-syntax-composition-api). Also look at how it's exposed [here](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/examples.html#form-submission), for usage with Options API.

Comment: yes, I'm using vue 3, can I use a computed for this?I've defined the `v$` in data property